# I created a password validation and I want to encrypt the password after validation completed.and print that password in console

Tags: java

```
package praveen;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class passwordencrypt {
    static String password;
    static String pattern = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
        while (true) {
            password = input.nextLine();
            if (password.matches(pattern)) {
                System.out.println("Valid Password");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Passowrd");
                System.out.println("Re enter your password");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I've created a validation for the password, now the password validated but how can I encrypt the valid password.

Comment: which algo u need to use for encryption?

Comment: @ hitesh ghuge MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm

Comment: try to avoid while(true) constructs, also avoid break statements. they make your code hard to read. In such a situation, using "while( noValidPasswordProvded )" makes it easy to understand that the loop runs until a valid password is provided.

if it says "while(true)" the reader might no see the "break" statement and wonder why this loops endlessly. If you nest whil / for / ... loops people might even think the break applies to the wrong loop.

Comment: please provide me the exact code

Comment: It's not really our job to write your code instead of you, don't you think?

Comment: as M. Prokhorov, just to outline things:  String userInput; boolean receivedValidInput = false; while(!receivedValidInput){ .... if (isValid(input) ) { receivedValidInput = true; userInput = ... ; } ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will encrypt pass using MD5

```
String beforeEncrypt = "hitesh";
String afterEncrypt = "";
try
{
    //Create MessageDigest object for MD5
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    //Update input string in message digest
    digest.update(beforeEncrypt.getBytes(), 0, beforeEncrypt.length());

    afterEncrypt = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString();

    System.out.println(afterEncrypt);

} 
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: After encryption. If i ask the user to re-enter the password.and Check the re-entered password against the encryted password.If both match, then dispaly a message: 'Authentication Successful'

Comment: Why you need to ask user to enter password twice?

Comment: that i also didnt understand my team lead question i will send u the same question he mailed me"After displaying the 'Valid Password' message.

Encrypt the password and print the encrypted password.

Ask the user to re-enter the password.

Check the re-entered password against the encryted password.

If both match, then dispaly a message: 'Authentication Successful'

If both did not match, then dispaly a message: 'Authentication Failed. Try again.'

The user must be able to enter the password again."

Comment: Ok.. just store the first pass and second pass in variable and compare them.

Comment: ur telling that second password is compared with encrypted password or what?

Comment: simply store both encrypted pass in two vars and then cmpare

Answer (score 0):

Using AES algorithm we can encrypt and decrypt any String

```
package encrypt;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class PasswordEncrypt {

String key = "passwordencrypts";
Cipher cipher;
Key aesKey;

public PasswordEncrypt() {
    try {
        aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PasswordEncrypt app = new PasswordEncrypt();
    System.out.println("enter string");
    PasswordEncrypt encrypt = new PasswordEncrypt();
    byte[] en = encrypt.encrypt(new Scanner(System.in).next());

    System.out.println(en + " encrypted");
    String de = encrypt.decrypt(en);
    System.out.println(de + "   decrypted");

}

private String decrypt(byte[] en) {
    String decrypted = "";
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(en));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decrypted;
}

private byte[] encrypt(String text) {
    byte[] en = null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        en = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return en;
}
}
```

Comment: to encrypt any String pass it  into "encrypt(String text)" and it returns byte[], if u want get back that String pass byte[] into  "decrypt(byte[] en)" method it will returns String as return type